# asp net ajax client side framework failed to load in VS 2008

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Visual Studio 2008
Configured Framework on IIS : 2.0

I have code for calling web service in asmx file.
I have put a scriptmanager to add web service.

```js
 // This function calls the Web Service method.
        function GetScrapTimeCalculation() {
            var Minutes = $("#" + '<%= NumericBoxQuantityMin.ClientID %>').val();
             Samples.AspNet.ScrapTimeCalculation.GetScrapTimeCalculation(document.getElementById(some parameters, OnSucceeded);
        }
```

```html
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptManager" EnablePageMethods="true">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Webservice/ScrapTimeCalculation.asmx" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Here's my web service code:

```
   <%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="Samples.AspNet.ScrapTimeCalculation" %>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Samples.AspNet
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class ScrapTimeCalculation : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetScrapTimeCalculation(some parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                Int32 fabID = Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlEncode(Fab_ID));
                string date = Server.HtmlEncode(ScrapDate);
                Int32 min = Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlEncode(minutes));
                Fab_dechet mObj = null;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(date) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Server.HtmlEncode(minutes)) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Server.HtmlEncode(Fab_ID)))
                {
                    mObj = new Fab_dechet();
                    return (mObj.GetScrapTimeCalculation(fabID, 0, date, min)).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return "0";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But when I run this code, I get following javascript error
"asp net ajax client side framework failed to load"

I run correctly when I use 4.0 framework!

Please help!
TIA!

Webconfig's Handler tag

```
<httpHandlers>
            <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*" />
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory" validate="false"/>

            <add verb="GET" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="Microsoft.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" validate="false"/>
            <add path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
            <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
            <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
            <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
```